Laptop BSOD ACPI Thermal Windows 11
My laptop is blue screen, and i go to safe mode to see what's issue in my laptop and then i see ACPI Thermal
ACPI thermal zone _TZ.TZ00 has been enumerated.
_PSV = OK
_TC1 = 0
_TC2 = 0
_TSP = Oms
_ACO = 344K
_AC1 = 328K
_AC2 = 323K
_AC3 = 318K
_AC4 = 313K
_AC5 = 0K
_AC6 = 0K
_AC7 = 0K
_AC8 = OK
_AC9 = 0K
_CRT = OK
_HOT = 0K
minimum throttle = 0
_CR3 = 0K
Please tell me what i can do to fix my laptop.

@Gantendo - Unlikely or the very least what’s been provided isn’t evidence of that fact.

“Please tell me what i can do to fix my laptop.” - There is nothing wrong with your laptop. Verify the air vents are not blocked. Make sure you don’t put the device to sleep instead of suspending it.

According to Lenovo, 70°C (343K) is a reasonable limit for computer heat management to slow or stop the CPU. AC0=344K indicates it just went over by one degree. This is not terrible, and likely no harm was done -- but to prevent recurrence, find the cause and try to fix it.

Be sure the vents are not restricted -- e.g., by putting the laptop on a soft surface, or by allowing dust to accumulate inside the case. (E.G., cats love to curl up around a warm PC, and they shed fur.)
Check that all fans turn smoothly, and run under use.
Check the Power Plan under Windows 11. The plan can be set to more quickly decrease CPU speed when hot.
Intel has recently warned manufacturers and users not to overclock some of the newest CPU's. This only applies to recent CPU's, though.
Some suggest reapplying heat-sink compound (thermal paste), but I'd try that only after attempting all other repairs. It is not a simple task, it is of use only if there is a clear thermal path from heat-sink (i.e., everything is cleaned, unobstructed, and fans work), and it can lead to permanent damage to the CPU or motherboard if done incorrectly.

